# How do I rewrite the vector equation of a line in symmetric form?

Tags: calculus, vectors

The problem given was "Given a the vector equation $r(t)=(−4−1t)i+(−3+1t)j+(3+5t)k$, rewrite this in terms of the symmetric equations for the line."

(quotient involving $x$)$=\quad -x- 4$

(quotient involving $y$)$=\quad\frac{y+3}{1}$

(quotient involving $z$) ?

I am having trouble figuring out the quotient involving $z$. I intially got $\frac{z-3}{5}$ but that was wrong. I googled how to do problems similiar to this one and it said to write them as parametric equations and then solve for $t$ which worked for the other two. I don't know what I am doing wrong and any help would be appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-write $\vec r=(-4\vec i-3\vec j+3\vec k)+t(-1\vec i+\vec j+ 5\vec k)$
So this line passes through the point $(-4,-3,3)$ having direction ratios as $(-1,1,5).$ The equation of liner is:
$$\frac{x+4}{-1}=\frac{y+3}{1}=\frac{z-3}{5}=t.$$

Answer (score 0):

In 3-dimensional space, a line's vector equation has the following form, right?
$$\begin{pmatrix} x \cr y \cr z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a_x \cr a_y \cr a_z \end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix} u_x \cr u_y \cr u_z \end{pmatrix}$$

Rearranging:
$$\begin{pmatrix} x-a_x  \cr y-a_y  \cr z-a_z \end{pmatrix}=t\begin{pmatrix} u_x \cr u_y \cr u_z \end{pmatrix}.$$

Dividing and multiplying:
$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{x-a_x}{u_x}  \cr \frac{y-a_y}{u_y}  \cr \frac{z-a_z}{u_z}  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}  t \cr t \cr t \end{pmatrix}.$$

Eliminating $t$ to obtain the symmetric form:
$$\frac{x-a_x}{u_x} = \frac{y-a_y}{u_y} = \frac{z-a_z}{u_z}.$$

Therefore, in your example,
$$\mathbf{r}(t)=(−4−1t)\mathbf{i}+(−3+1t)\mathbf{j}+(3+5t)\mathbf{k} \\
\implies \frac{x+4}{-1} = \frac{y+3}{1} = \frac{z-3}{5}.$$